# Electrolysis of auric chloride solvent with different metals in anode and cathode

Tags: electrochemistry

**Question:**

> Write down possible reaction in anode and cathode for electrolysis of $\ce{AuCl3}$ with solid $\ce{Au}$ electrode in anode and solid $\ce{Ag}$ electrode in cathode.

As far, I could write the anode reaction. In the anode, there are 3 competitors ($\ce{Au}$ electrode/$\ce{Cl-}$/$\ce{H2O}$), so the final reaction would be

$$\ce{2Cl- -> Cl2 + 2e-}$$

But I couldn't figure the cathode reaction because there are 3 competitors in cathode ($\ce{Ag}$ electrode/$\ce{Au3+}$/$\ce{H2O}$) that I have no idea what I need to do with the $\ce{Ag}$ here.

Some sources said $\ce{Ag}$  is an inert metal. How the reaction for cathode would be?

Comment: How is Ag a competitor at cathode?